# Select two values ​from the same reference

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table A

```
ID   ref   meta   value

5    134   year   2000
5    156   type   new
5    187   order   3
5    199   color  red
```

and I want it back

```
ID   year  type

5    2000  new
```

I'm trying to do it with

```
CASE WHEN itm.meta_key = 'year' THEN itm.value END as year,
CASE WHEN itm.meta_key = 'type' THEN itm.value END as type
```

but only checks the first 'meta' that finds in DDBB.
How should I do it?

Comment: Can we assume that "meta" keys are unique for each ID?  That is, ID no. 5 won't have two rows for 'year'?

Answer (score 3):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT id, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN itm.meta_key = 'year' THEN itm.value END) as year,
       MAX(CASE WHEN itm.meta_key = 'type' THEN itm.value END) as type
FROM itm
GROUP BY id;
```